# Listbox items "invisibles" when refreshing data (winform)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, display

I have a problem with my listbox : if I change anything in the data (like adding an item or deleting one), the items become invisble but actually is still "here" (I can see it because I have made a sort of tooltip when my mouse go hover it).

The purpose of my listbox is to show a list of scene (like files) when the user select an folder with a combobox.

Here is my code :

```
public partial class FormScenario : Form
{
    BindingList<Folder> blFolders = new BindingList<Folder>();
    BindingList<Scene> blScenes = new BindingList<Scene>();

    public FormScenario(FormMainPanel fParent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FParent = fParent;
    }

    public void Refresh_blScenes()
    {
        lb_scenes.DataSource = null;
        lb_scenes.Items.Clear();
        lb_scenes.DataSource = this.blScenes;
        lb_scenes.DisplayMember = "SceneName";

        //attempt to fix the bug ... not working
        lb_scenes.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal;
        lb_scenes.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    public void Populate_Scene_Datas()
    {
        blScenes.Clear();
        Folder fol = (Folder)cb_listfolders.SelectedItem;
        if (fol != null){
            foreach (Scene sce in fol.ListScenes){
                this.blScenes.Add(sce);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it is useful, there is my objects :

```
class Folder
{
    public Int32 IdFolder { get; set; }
    public String FolderName { get; set; }
    public String FolderInfo { get; set; }

    // contains the list to show in the listbox 
    public List<Scene> ListScenes = new List<Scene>();
}

class Scene
{
    public Int32 IdScene { get; set; }
    public String SceneName { get; set; }
    public byte[] SceneDesc { get; set; }
    public byte[] SceneInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I use these functions in the following order :

```
Populate_Scene_Datas();
Refresh_blScenes();
```

if somebody give me a hint or a answer at this problem, it will be very helpfull !

Thanks you !

Comment: have you tried to set Display Member and Selected Value properties.

Comment: i think you have to call **Populate_Scene_Datas()** function when you are adding or deleting data

Comment: @VickyS I have set Displaymember (you can see it in my post) but not selectedvalue... I will try it !

Comment: @M.Y.Mnu It's actually the case. And the listbox doesn't show anything with the first loading too.

Comment: Can you show the code you use for adding or deleting an item?

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah I can't, because I haven't written this part of code yet. The listbox is updated by the two functions when the combox change (the combox contain a list of "Folder" Object).
I don't think there is a problem with the alimentation of list: with the debug I can see that the BindingList is correctly updated....

Comment: Stupid question because I've faced this in web development: Is the font colour set to white?

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah I have tested this (by changing the background in black... in case of something change the font color) but ... not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution... but I can't explain why it is working.
I'm posting this if someone encounter the same problem.

I have change this :

```
lb_scenes.DataSource = this.blScenes;
```

by :

```
lb_scenes.Items.AddRange(blScenes.ToArray());
```